# How to parse legacy MS JSON date that has a timezone offset

Tags: date-fns

I am trying to parse a date string with date-fns and target string is in the old MS JSON date format, '/Date(xxxxxx+xxxx)/'.

An example: /Date(47896200000+0500)/

If I drop the timezone offset ("+0500") then this works:

```
parse(
    '/Date(47896200000)/',
    "'/Date('T')/'",
    new Date()
);
```

But how do I parse the date string when there IS a timestamp? I can't figure out what the format string should be.

Comment: have you tried T+Z or TZ in the literal ?

Comment: If I'm understanding the docs correctly, date-fns uses "x" for timezone (https://date-fns.org/v2.24.0/docs/parse) and I tried Tx and T+x but date-fns gives me: "The format string mustn't contain `T` and `x` at the same time"